# Android findViewById null pointer

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

From activity_settings.xml

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/editText" android:text="text" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button" android:text="button"/>
```

From MyActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    this.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText txt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),txt.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        });
...
```

If I click the button I get

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

Just for test I tried and succeeded

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    EditText txt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),txt.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I don't get why button is ok but editText is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `findViewById()` on the `view` that was clicked. Your button does not have the edittext as its child. You should query the activity view hierarchy instead: replace

```
view.findViewById(R.id.editText)
```

with

```
findViewById(R.id.editText)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
EditText txt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

to

```
EditText txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Your are looking for your EditText control in the View which was clicked - and that's obviously the Button. You have to search through the Activity's layout file.